# Duplication in ArrayList when I split it

Tags: java, arraylist, split

I have an `ArrayList` of `Dico` and I try to split it in multiple ArrayLists, but this causes some duplication.

This is the Dico class:

```
public class Dico implements Comparable {
    private final String m_term;
    private double m_weight;
    private final int m_Id_doc;

    public Dico(int Id_Doc, String Term, double tf_ief) {
        this.m_Id_doc = Id_Doc;
        this.m_term = Term;
        this.m_weight = tf_ief;
    }

    public String getTerm() {
        return this.m_term;
    }

    public double getWeight() {
        return this.m_weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(double weight) {
        this.m_weight = weight;
    }

    public int getDocId() {
        return this.m_Id_doc;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object another) throws ClassCastException {
        if (!(another instanceof Dico))
            throw new ClassCastException("A Dico object expected.");
        int anotherDocid = ((Dico) another).getDocId();
        return this.getDocId() - anotherDocid;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "id" + getDocId() + "term" + getTerm() + "weight" + getWeight() + "";
    }
}
```

And `split_dico`function that is use to do this:

```
public static void split_dico(List<Dico> list) {
    int[] changes = new int[list.size() + 1]; // allow for max changes--> contain index of subList
    Arrays.fill(changes, -1); // if an index is not used, will remain -1
    changes[0] = 0;
    int change = 1;
    int id = list.get(0).getDocId();
    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        Dico dic_entry = list.get(i);
        if (id != dic_entry.getDocId()) {
            changes[change++] = i;
            id = dic_entry.getDocId();
        }
    }
    changes[change] = list.size(); // end of last change segment
    List<List<Dico>> sublists = new ArrayList<>(change);
    for (int i = 0; i < change; i++) {
        sublists.add(list.subList(changes[i], changes[i + 1]));
        System.out.println(sublists);
    }
}
```

Test:

```
List<Dico> list = Arrays.asList(new Dico(1, "foo", 1),
    new Dico(7, "zoo", 5),
    new Dico(2, "foo", 1),
    new Dico(3, "foo", 1),
    new Dico(1, "bar", 2),
    new Dico(4, "zoo", 0.5),
    new Dico(2, "bar", 2),
    new Dico(3, "baz", 3));
Collections.sort(list_new);
split_dico(list_new);
```

Output:

```
[[doc id : 1 term : foo weight : 2.2, doc id : 1 term : bar weight : 6.6]]

[[doc id : 1 term : foo weight : 2.2, doc id : 1 term : bar weight : 6.6], [doc id : 2 term : foo weight : 2.2, doc id : 2 term : bar weight : 6.6]]

[[doc id : 1 term : foo weight : 2.2, doc id : 1 term : bar weight : 6.6], [doc id : 2 term : foo weight : 2.2, doc id : 2 term : bar weight : 6.6], [doc id : 3 term : foo weight : 2.2]]

[[doc id : 1 term : foo weight : 2.2, doc id : 1 term : bar weight : 6.6], [doc id : 2 term : foo weight : 2.2, doc id : 2 term : bar weight : 6.6], [doc id : 3 term : foo weight : 2.2], [doc id : 4 term : zoo weight : 0.15]]

[[doc id : 1 term : foo weight : 2.2, doc id : 1 term : bar weight : 6.6], [doc id : 2 term : foo weight : 2.2, doc id : 2 term : bar weight : 6.6], [doc id : 3 term : foo weight : 2.2], [doc id : 4 term : zoo weight : 0.15], [doc id : 7 term : zoo weight : 1.5]]
```

I don't understand the problem with this function.

Comment: Don't use `Comparable` as a raw type. Use `Comparable<Dico>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

in your printing loop you are printing the whole list of **sublists** after adding a new sublist.

Instead, depending on your requirements, you should print only when you are finished with populating **sublists**

Comment: If i do that i will print all sublists but i want to use it separately each list contain must contain doc with same id.
I have solution to split that ArrayList but the complexity for this is so high for 1 millions terms.
i am searching for a fastest solution

Comment: the solution is the next:
           
    for (List<Dico> sublist : sublists) 
     {
             System.out.println(sublist);
      }
thanks @micklesh

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry about this stupid question it is so rediculus,i want too about more speed soltion:

```
public static void split_dico(List<Dico> list)
   {
   int[] changes = new int[list.size() + 1]; // allow for max changes--> contain index of subList
Arrays.fill(changes, -1); // if an index is not used, will remain -1
changes[0] = 0;
int change = 1;
int id = list.get(0).getDocId();
for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++)
{
    Dico dic_entry = list.get(i);
    if (id != dic_entry.getDocId()) 
    {
        changes[change++] = i;
        id = dic_entry.getDocId();
    }
}
changes[change] = list.size(); // end of last change segment
List<List<Dico>> sublists = new ArrayList<>(change);
for (int i = 0; i < change; i++) 
{
    sublists.add(list.subList(changes[i], changes[i + 1]));

 } 
  for (int i = 1; i < sublists.size(); i++)
 {
      lists <Dico> = sublists.get(i);
      system.out.println(lists);

 }
 }
```

OUTPUT:

```
 [[doc id : 1 term : foo weight : 2.2, doc id : 1 term : bar weight : 6.6], [doc id : 2 term : foo weight : 2.2, doc id : 2 term : bar weight : 6.6], [doc id : 3 term : foo weight : 2.2], [doc id : 4 term : zoo weight : 0.15], [doc id : 7 term : zoo weight : 1.5]]
```